# Call actuator within controller Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to expose a custom endpoint which internally calls spring actuator. but i am getting  Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out.

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/${spring.application.name}/actuator/health")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser() {
        ResponseEntity<Map> entity = this.restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:" + this.port
                + "/actuator/health", Map.class);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Is there any way to make it work.

Comment: Are you able to call the actuator endpoint from postman? If yes the endpoint is working and I cannot see why you wouldn't be able to call it from within your app. Check the url/port you are calling. Anyway if you need to access health information you can reach to them without calling the endpoint, you can inject HealthEndpoint (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthEndpoint.html) and access them.

Comment: Yes, i am able to call it from postman.

Comment: If you don't provide more information it won't be easy to help you.

Comment: Yes, i am able to call actuator endpoint from postman. Inspite of that i am not able to call it from controller. url and port is all fine. I get Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Comment: Actuator port may be different from application port. Where are you getting the port from?

Comment: Port is same i am getting from application.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no need to create your own endpoint, just set `management.endpoints.web.base-path=${spring.application.name}` in `application.properties`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html.

Comment: Thank you, you saved lot of my time